# How to solve the convex combination problem of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-equations

Let $A \succeq B$ denote matrix $A-B$ is positive semidefinite, and here is the definition of **redundant**(all the matrix dimensions are $N\times N$ ):

Given a set of matrix $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^{l}$, if there exist nonnegative constants $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{l}$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha_i=  1,  \text{  and  }  A \succeq \sum_{i=1}^{l}\alpha_i B_i$$
then we say the A  is **redundant**.

Here is the question: how to determine whether an arbitrary $A$ is **redundant** given the set of matrix  $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^{l}$ ?

Here is my incomplete solution:

Since the "positive semidefinite" problem is hard to handle, I suppose to solve "positive definite" problem:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha=  1,  \text{  and  }  A \succ \sum_{i=1}^{l}\alpha_i B_i$$

Then, I use this characterization:
**Its leading principal minors are all positive.**  Assume the leading principal minors of $A$ are $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{N}$, $B_i$ are $\{b_{ij}\}_{j=1}^{N}$, then we have

$$a_j > \sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha_i b_{ij}, \forall j$$

So the question could be changed  to an optimization problem:

$$\text{minimize} \sum_{i=1}^{l}\alpha_i$$
$$\text{subject to  }a_j \gt \sum_{i=1}^{l} \alpha_i b_{ij}, \forall j  \text{  and  } \alpha_i \geq 0, \forall i$$

If the solution shows that  $\sum_{i=1}^{l}\alpha_i$ is less than 1, then $A$ is redundant.

Comment: Do you want the $\alpha_i's$ to be $ > 0$ or $ \ge 0$ ? You seem to be using $ > 0$ and $ \ge 0$ interchangeably.

Comment: @dohmatob sorry, this is a typo, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of the idea:** Without any relaxions, etc., your problem can be conveniently rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray}
\underset{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^l}{\text{maximize }}c^T\alpha \text{ subject to } F(\alpha) \succeq 0, \alpha \ge 0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $F(\alpha) := A - \sum_{1 \le i \le l}\alpha_iB_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times 1}$ is a column vector of $1$'s.

We immediately recognize the above problem is a LCP (linear convex program) with positive-semi-definiteness constraints. Such problems have been studied extensively in the [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/semidef_prog.pdf).

If the maximal value $c^T\alpha^* \ge 1$, then $A$ is "redundant".

Comment: Thanks! But I still wonder whether the computation complexity is reasonable?

Comment: @SandyX: If my post was useful for your question, then  consider accepting it first. Then, we can talk about cosmetic details. Otherwise it's not worth the effort, and represents a waste of useful time.

Comment: I have accepted it, though I forgot to upvote it.

Comment: I believe that your answer is right

Comment: OK :) About complexity of solving the problem, the reference paper says their algorithms can scale as $\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})$ (see subsection 5.7). Is the computation worthwhile ? Well it depends on what you're trying to do. From your definition, asking where a matrix is "redundant" (I was unfamiliar with the terminology before I saw your question) seems to be a tricky thing to check, and I can't think of a "one-shot" / non-iterative way of doing it. What's  the / an application of your question about redundancy of matrices ?

Comment: There maybe, I will study in it. Thanks